# Update with Unique Field

Tags: mysql

I am using MySQL and I currently have a data table that looks like this:

```
+---------+-----------------+-------------------+-----------+
| user_id |      email      |      password     | is_active |
+---------+-----------------+-------------------+-----------+
|    1    | admin@admin.com | [hashed_password] |     0     |
+---------+-----------------+-------------------+-----------+
|    2    |  user@user.com  | [hashed_password] |     0     |
+---------+-----------------+-------------------+-----------+
```

Where `user_id` is the primary, unique, auto-incremented field and `email` is a unique field.

I want to allow the user to update their email address and password, the issue that I'm running into is structuring my SELECT statement to verify that the desired `email` is not already in use and if it is in use then make sure that the `user_id` matches.

So for example, if the person who is `user_id` #2 decides to submit the following values:

```
Values:
+---------+-----------------+--------------------+-----------+
| user_id |      email      |      password      | is_active |
+---------+-----------------+--------------------+-----------+
|    2    | admin@admin.com |      new value     |     0     |
+---------+-----------------+--------------------+-----------+
```

Result should return `False` since `admin@admin.com` exists for `user_id` #1 and the value for `user_id` is 2

```
Values:
+---------+-----------------+--------------------+-----------+
| user_id |      email      |      password      | is_active |
+---------+-----------------+--------------------+-----------+
|    2    |  user@user.com  |      new value     |     0     |
+---------+-----------------+--------------------+-----------+
```

Result should return `True` since even though `user@user.com` exists for user_id #2 the value for `user_id` matches that of which the email already belongs to

I have tried the following code, and it returns a value in case #2 in my example above but it does not return a value at all in case #1:

```
SELECT
    COUNT(`user_id`) > 0
FROM
    `user`
GROUP BY
    `user_id`
HAVING
    SUM(CASE WHEN `user`.`email`="admin@admin.com" THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) <> 0 AND
    SUM(CASE WHEN `user`.`user_id`=1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) <> 0
```

Comment: Is it possible that you are overcomplicating things? Why don't you just check if the email belongs to another user? `select user_id from user where email = 'admin@admin.com'`

Comment: @PaulSpiegel - because what if the user with that email address wants to change his email?

Comment: Just compare his `user_id` with what  you get from the query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to check first. Just try to perform the `UPDATE`. If the email is used in another row, this will fail because of the unique index on the `email` column. You can test for that error and report that the email is in use.

If you do it your way, you need to use a transaction between the `SELECT` and `UPDATE` queries, otherwise someone could slip in between them and create a row with the desired email.

Comment: I did not think about somebody slipping in between the two statements. I ultimately went with your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select  email, user_id, if(user_id = 2, 1, 0) as owner from user where email ="admin@admin.com"
```

If current user (Id 2) own checked email column owner will return 1, otherwise 0

But if you really want to check it only by query (which is not good idea)...

```
Select 
If(u2.email is null or u1.user_id = u2.user_id, 1, 0) as result
From user u1
Left join user u2 on (u2.email = "admin@admin.com" )
Where u1.user_id = 2
```

So you need to put to query email and user id.
Note: I did not test query, so there could be errors. Its just example of approach